# Computing the closure under a set of FDs

Tags: database, closures, relation, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

I am confused on how to compute the closure under a set of FDs. The actual question that I have is

> Relation R{A, B, C, D, E} satisfies the following FDs:
> A→D AB → C E→B
>
> Compute the closure of {A,E}+ under this set of FD. Also what is the candidate key?

Here is what I thought the answer would be but I have no idea if I am correct. I tried looking it up online, but nothing really helped me out. So hopefully someone here can help me.

```
A→A
A→AB
A→ABCD
A→ABCDE
```

A candidate key would be A.

Is this correct? Also I don't know why the formatting looks weird.... I indented 4 spaces for code....

Comment: What are the instructions for computing the closure of a set of FDs? How did you come up with what you thought was the answer? What are the instructions for determining a CK? How did you come up with A as a CK? Show "effort".

Comment: @philipxy I honestly don't know, thats why I asked on here for help. I couldn't find a good answer online when I googled it. Can you point me towards a good site for help?

Comment: But you were given an assignment, what resources were you told to use? I just googled "stackoverflow compute closure of a set of functional dependencies" and the second hit had an algorithm & references. Also: you "honestly don't know" how the possible answer got into your question??

Comment: You were asked to compute the closure of AE. You computed the closure of A, and you did *that* incorrectly. A->B is not true, for example. Neither is A->E. Which textbook did your teacher assign? Look in it for an algorithm to compute the closure of a set of attributes.